# ansible-doc getting started?

Tags: ansible, troubleshooting, documentation, syntax

Is there a `vimtutor` eqvivalent to ansible?

I know I can read up on the syntax of a particular module using `ansible-doc <module>` - but what if I can't recall the module name?

If I find myself without internet with only ansible-doc available - how can I get assistance on writing the playbook basics? An entry point to help me remember the `- name:` before `block` for instance.

```
$ ansible-doc block
[WARNING]: block was not found
```

Comment: There is no such facility in ansible.

Comment: You could clone [the documentation](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-documentation/) to have it available without internet access.

Comment: Cloning is not an option if you for instance need to jug your memory whilst doing the test to get a RHCSE.

Comment: The web documentation is available during the RHCE.

Comment: > Internet access is not provided during the exam, and you will not be permitted to bring any hard copy or electronic documentation into the exam.